# Multiply a list with a matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, matrix-multiplication, lapply

A is a list of 8 matrices dimension 2x2, so length of A=8. How can I multiply each matrix in A with a matrix B dimension 2x2 to get a new list of 8 matrices dim2x2? A and B are already defined.

I know "lapply" may help, but I'm still stuck. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: @DavidHeckmann you mean the exact matrices I have or the code i failed to write properly?

Comment: preferably both, but code to produce the matrices would be a good start.

Comment: ok thanks! next time i will do.:)

Comment: `lapply(list_of_matrices, function(M) {M %*% B})`?

You can always amend your question using the "edit" link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
A = list(a = matrix(1:4, 2), b = matrix(2:5, 2))
B = matrix(3:6, 2)
lapply(A, FUN = function(x) x %*% B)
```

I guess this is what you need, next time please provide a reproducible example.